# boost asio https post request with empty body

Tags: c++, http, http-headers, boost-asio

I'm sending a post request over a tcp socket using the boost asio library. On the server side the request is received but there's no params, what's going on?

```
boost::asio::streambuf request_;
std::string postfields ("username=user1&password=any");
std::ostream request_stream(&request_);
request_stream << "POST " << /somepath << " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
request_stream << "Host: " << somehost.com << "\r\n";
request_stream << "User-Agent: C/1.0" << "\r\n";
request_stream << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded \r\n";
request_stream << "Accept: application/json\r\n";
request_stream << "Content-Length: " << postfields.length() << "\r\n"
request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
request_stream << postfields;
request_stream << "\n\n"; // tried with and without this line

boost::asio::async_write(socket_, request_,
                      boost::bind(&client::handle_write_request, shared_from_this(),
                              boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

When I print the request it looks like this

```
POST /somepath HTTP/1.1
Host: somehost.com
User-Agent: C/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json
Connection: close

username=user1&password=any
```

On the serverside the body is empty, there's no params. What could be wrong here?

Please don't mark this as duplicate as I've exhausted all the stackoverflow questions similar to this. Thanks

Comment: This isn't the problem but missed the semi-colon on the line request_stream << "Content-Length: " << postfields.length() << "\r\n"; // .

Comment: I've tagged your question with `http` and `http-headers` since it's really about the content of a `http post` request.